# Jmeter. Запись результатов в nongui режиме

Tags: jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Вопрос в следующем:

Запускаю тест-план и собираю результаты листнеров в файлы, но обнаружил, что jmeter в nongui режиме не группирует запросы по названию, а разделяет их по какому-то счетчику

Выглядит это для summary report следующим образом:
[image: Summary Report]

В графическом представлении, например в листнере времени отклика, это выглядит еще хуже, что делает графики совершенно не читаемыми:

[image: Response Time Graph]

Пожалуйста, помогите сделать так, чтобы записанные в nongui результаты группировались по имени запроса и выводились средний результат так же, как это происходит в GUI - режиме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение начиная с версии JMeter 5.0, см [Bug 62550 - Modify SubResult Naming Policy](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62550)

1. Можно убрать галку Save Sub Results

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Можно добавить следующую строчку в [user.properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#sample_results):

   ```
   subresults.disable_renaming=true
   ```
3. А вообще [пользоваться листенерами для сохранения результатов не лучшая идея](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), если вы запускаете тест в режиме nongui - вся необходимая информация сохраняется в .jtl файле, листенеры только считают метрики/рендерят графики.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только что обнаружил ответ на свой вопрос экспериментальным путем, обнаружив, что вывод похож на тот, что получается во View Results Tree, если открыть запрос. Так и догадался

Приходится писать результаты таким образом, потому что тест-план большой и необходимы читаемые графики, поэтому тест-план разбит на 4 группы потоков, в каждом свой summary-listner